# How to add a list in this calendarview to a specific date?

Tags: calendar

I am working in a calender application in winui and need to add a list on a specific date

I have tried adding a text block and next I would like to change it to a list

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate but take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75202353/how-to-add-textblock-to-calendarview-in-winui) and add more ``TextBoxes``. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: By "list", you mean a few ``TextBoxes`` right? or you mean a ``ListView`` control?

Comment: Yes sir its the list view, i need to add the list view in the calenderdayitem in a specific date

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: How here dependency property works? Can you explain this

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer you question but, by making DayItems DependencyProperty, we can use binding as it's in the example. This way, wen can bind to a collection in a ViewModel class.

Comment: Yes code works but i can't understand the flow how the data bind to the ui.

Comment: Not only user controls, custom controls and built in controls like buttons have dependency properties for binding.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the doubt,Difference between normal binding vs dependency ?

Comment: This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0) is for WPF but will help you understand. And let me mention that it's not recommended to ask extended questions in the comments. You should see if your extended question is already answered in other questions. If not, consider posting a new question.

Comment: Here how can we  bind another parameter->DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), "Tommorrow"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a user control like this one:

**CustomCalendarView.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="CalendarViewTests.CustomCalendarView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:CalendarViewTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <CalendarView
            x:Name="CalendarViewControl"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            CalendarItemBorderBrush="DimGray"
            CalendarItemBorderThickness="1"
            CalendarItemCornerRadius="0"
            DayItemFontSize="10"
            DayItemFontWeight="ExtraLight"
            HorizontalDayItemAlignment="Center"
            VerticalDayItemAlignment="Top">
            <CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
                <Style TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid
                                    Margin="5"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
        </CalendarView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CustomCalenderView.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CalendarViewTests;

public record CustomCalendarViewDayItem
{
    public CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime dateTime, string text)
    {
        DateTime = dateTime;
        Text = text;
    }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; }

    public string Text { get; }
}

public sealed partial class CustomCalendarView : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DayItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(DayItems),
        typeof(IEnumerable<CustomCalendarViewDayItem>),
        typeof(CustomCalendarView),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomCalendarView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CalendarViewControl.CalendarViewDayItemChanging += CalendarViewControl_CalendarViewDayItemChanging;
    }

    public IEnumerable<CustomCalendarViewDayItem> DayItems
    {
        get => (IEnumerable<CustomCalendarViewDayItem>)GetValue(DayItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(DayItemsProperty, value);
    }

    private void CalendarViewControl_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (DayItems.Where(x => DateOnly.FromDateTime(x.DateTime) == DateOnly.FromDateTime(args.Item.Date.Date))
            .Select(x => x.Text) is IEnumerable<string> dayItems)
        {
            args.Item.DataContext = dayItems;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="CalendarViewTests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:CalendarViewTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <local:CustomCalendarView DayItems="{x:Bind DayItems, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CalendarViewTests;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), "5 days ago"));
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now, "Todo 1"));
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now, "Todo 2"));
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now, "Todo 3"));
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now, "Todo 4"));
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now, "Todo 5"));
        DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), "Tommorrow"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomCalendarViewDayItem> DayItems { get; } = new();
}
```