# How to bind background color to binded listview?

Tags: binding

How can we bind the color here ?

```
DayItems.Add(new CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), "Tommorrow"));
```

Comment: It seems this question is based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266361/how-to-add-a-list-in-this-calendarview-to-a-specific-date?noredirect=1#comment133690469_75266361) of yours. Can you edit your question and make it clear that this is a follow up question? See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378375/can-i-ask-about-an-extended-solution-of-another-question). You don't need to paste all of the code but at least a link to the original question would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property on the [CustomCalendarViewDayItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266361/how-to-add-a-list-in-this-calendarview-to-a-specific-date?noredirect=1#comment133690469_75266361:%7E:text=public%20record%20CustomCalendarViewDayItem%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime%20dateTime%2C%20string%20text)%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DateTime%20%3D%20dateTime%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Text%20%3D%20text%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20DateTime%20DateTime%20%7B%20get%3B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20string%20Text%20%7B%20get%3B%20%7D%0A%7D) in my answer for your original question:

```cs
public record CustomCalendarViewDayItem
{
    public CustomCalendarViewDayItem(DateTime dateTime, string text)
    {
        DateTime = dateTime;
        Text = text;
    }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; }

    public string Text { get; }

    public Brush Background { get; }
}
```

And change how to create the list:

```cs
private void CalendarViewControl_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (DayItems.Where(x => DateOnly.FromDateTime(x.DateTime) == DateOnly.FromDateTime(args.Item.Date.Date))
            .Select(x => x) is IEnumerable<CustomCalendarViewDayItem> dayItems)
    {
        args.Item.DataContext = dayItems;
    }
}
```

And the `CalendarViewDayItemStyle` should look like this:

```xml
<CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
    <Style TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid
                        Margin="5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CustomCalendarViewDayItem">
                                    <ListViewItem
                                        Background="{x:Bind Background}"
                                        Content="{x:Bind Text}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</CalendarView.CalendarViewDayItemStyle>
```